# differentiate between box collider of two different Game Objects in UNITY

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision, collider

I have two `GameObjects` `Body1` and `Body2`, Both have separate `BoxCollider`. i want to identify which `GameObject` (`Body1` or `Body2`) have hit the other.

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/400393/detect-collision-between-object-and-box-collider.html

Comment: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/detecting-collisions-oncollisionenter

Answer (score 0):

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
    {
        Debug.Log(col.gameObject.name);
    }
```

With this you can get the name of the object. But if i got your question correct, both of them have collider and `body1` hits `body2` is quite same with `body2` hits `body1`

You can make the discrimination with, if one of them is standing still (no position changed) and other one is moving, then you can say `body1` hits `body2` or whatever your condition is.

To achive this you can use a bool, like `isObjectMoving`. You can check it in `Update()` . If `transform.position` is changing bool will be true and you will check it in if statement

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
        {
            if(col.gameObject.getComponent<YourBoolScriptName>().isObjectMoving == true)
            //Debug.Log(the other body hit me);
        }
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!